# Texture2dProgram - where is the glUniform for sTexture defined

Tags: android, opengl-es, grafika

looking at the code in Texture2dProgram.java I cannot find the where the uniform for sTexture is defined. Others like aPosition are defined in the constructor.

Being a novice in opengl it looks like the fragment shader uses the current texture unit and a texture is bound to that texture unit so is sTexture a default pre defined name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magic about `sTexture`.  It's a `sampler2D`, which has a default value of 0 (or `GL_TEXTURE0`), which is what we want.  There's no need to change its value, hence no need to get the uniform address.